# Using document.activeElement with an onChange event to validate a textbox only after textbox change is completed

Tags: javascript, textbox, validation

I have already implemented a version of the code below on my development system.

> function validateTextBox(textBoxId) {
>     var textBox = document.getElementById(textBoxId);
>     if(document.activeElement.id != textBox.id) {
>       ***do validation***
>     }
>       }

The HTML is similar to:
`<input type="text" id="ValidateMe" onChange="validateTextBox('ValidateMe');"/>`

The idea is that validation takes place only after the user has completed editing the textbox and that, unlike an onBlur event, validation only fires when the value of the textbox has actually changed.

It seems to work I'm just leery of using it without some review and feedback. **I haven't seen any similar code examples.** So please give me your thoughts on the implementation and any alternate ideas you may have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a fine solution. Do keep in mind that the onchange event will typically only fire when the focus changes (ie. onblur)

If you want to do validation while the user is typing you can use onkeydown/onkeyup/onkeypress but that's quite a ways harder.

Additionally you can use `this` so you don't have to assign an id to each field and remember to pass it to the validate function:

```
function validate(input_element) {
    alert(input_element.value)
}
<input type="text" name="name" onchange="validate(this);"/>
```

Comment: Ok that's my bad. I solved a problem that doesn't exist. No wonder it was worked so well. I think i was thinking of the onChange event when using MS Access.  

Anyway, thank you for your quick reply and I will look at using `this` in my code.

Thanks Again